# aniplot でアニメーションのプロットを線で繋ぎたい

Tags: python, matplotlib

初めて利用させていただきます。
拙い部分もあるかと思いますがお付き合いいただければ幸いです。

現在、プロットを任意の座標通りに動かすアニメーションを作成しており、点を動かすことには成功しているのですが、そのアニメーションのプロットを線で繋ぎたいと考えております。

以下、現在完成しているコードです。

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import animatplot as amp
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import math

#グラフの描画
def plot_animation(ref_df):
    #X軸・Y軸のデータ取得
    X_data = 0
    Y_data = 0
    #refの経路描画
    time_data_np = np.array(ref_df["time"])
    x_np = np.array(ref_df["x"])
    y_np = np.array(ref_df["y"])
    x2_np = np.array(ref_df["x2"])
    y2_np = np.array(ref_df["y2"])
    x3_np = np.array(ref_df["x3"])
    y3_np = np.array(ref_df["y3"])
    x4_np = np.array(ref_df["x4"])
    y4_np = np.array(ref_df["y4"])
    x5_np = np.array(ref_df["x5"])
    y5_np = np.array(ref_df["y5"])
    x6_np = np.array(ref_df["x6"])
    y6_np = np.array(ref_df["y6"])
    x7_np = np.array(ref_df["x7"])
    y7_np = np.array(ref_df["y7"])
    x8_np = np.array(ref_df["x8"])
    y8_np = np.array(ref_df["y8"])
    x9_np = np.array(ref_df["x9"])
    y9_np = np.array(ref_df["y9"])
    x10_np = np.array(ref_df["x10"])
    y10_np = np.array(ref_df["y10"])
    x11_np = np.array(ref_df["x11"])
    y11_np = np.array(ref_df["y11"])
    x12_np = np.array(ref_df["x12"])
    y12_np = np.array(ref_df["y12"])
    x13_np = np.array(ref_df["x13"])
    y13_np = np.array(ref_df["y13"])
    x14_np = np.array(ref_df["x14"])
    y14_np = np.array(ref_df["y14"])
    x15_np = np.array(ref_df["x15"])
    y15_np = np.array(ref_df["y15"])
    x16_np = np.array(ref_df["x16"])
    y16_np = np.array(ref_df["y16"])
    x17_np = np.array(ref_df["x17"])
    y17_np = np.array(ref_df["y17"])
    x18_np = np.array(ref_df["x18"])
    y18_np = np.array(ref_df["y18"])
    x19_np = np.array(ref_df["x19"])
    y19_np = np.array(ref_df["y19"])
    x20_np = np.array(ref_df["x20"])
    y20_np = np.array(ref_df["y20"])
    x21_np = np.array(ref_df["x21"])
    y21_np = np.array(ref_df["y21"])
    x22_np = np.array(ref_df["x22"])
    y22_np = np.array(ref_df["y22"])
    x23_np = np.array(ref_df["x23"])
    y23_np = np.array(ref_df["y23"])
    
  
    Xs_log =np.asarray([x_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) #X軸データ × 時間軸 分の配列
    Ys_log =[y_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             #Y軸データ × 時間軸 分の配列
    Xs2_log =np.asarray([x2_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys2_log =[y2_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             
    Xs3_log =np.asarray([x3_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys3_log =[y3_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             
    Xs4_log =np.asarray([x4_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys4_log =[y4_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             
    Xs5_log =np.asarray([x5_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys5_log =[y5_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             
    Xs6_log =np.asarray([x6_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys6_log =[y6_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             
    Xs7_log =np.asarray([x7_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys7_log =[y7_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             
    Xs8_log =np.asarray([x8_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys8_log =[y8_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             
    Xs9_log =np.asarray([x9_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys9_log =[y9_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             
    Xs10_log =np.asarray([x10_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys10_log =[y10_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             
    Xs11_log =np.asarray([x11_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys11_log =[y11_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             
    Xs12_log =np.asarray([x12_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys12_log =[y12_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             
    Xs13_log =np.asarray([x13_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys13_log =[y13_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             
    Xs14_log =np.asarray([x14_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys14_log =[y14_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             
    Xs15_log =np.asarray([x15_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys15_log =[y15_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             
    Xs16_log =np.asarray([x16_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys16_log =[y16_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             
    Xs17_log =np.asarray([x17_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys17_log =[y17_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             
    Xs18_log =np.asarray([x18_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys18_log =[y18_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             
    Xs19_log =np.asarray([x19_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys19_log =[y19_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             
    Xs20_log =np.asarray([x20_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys20_log =[y20_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             
    Xs21_log =np.asarray([x21_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys21_log =[y21_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             
    Xs22_log =np.asarray([x22_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys22_log =[y22_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             
    Xs23_log =np.asarray([x23_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]) 
    Ys23_log =[y23_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)]             


    Time_log =np.asarray([time_data_np[t:t+1] for t in range(len(time_data_np)-1)])

    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1), (0,0), rowspan=3)

    ax1.set_xlim([-0.5, 1.3])      
    ax1.set_ylim([-0.1, 0.8])      

    block = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs_log, Ys_log,ax=ax1)
    block2 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs2_log, Ys2_log,ax=ax1)
    block3 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs3_log, Ys3_log,ax=ax1)
    block4 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs4_log, Ys4_log,ax=ax1)
    block5 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs5_log, Ys5_log,ax=ax1)
    block6 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs6_log, Ys6_log,ax=ax1)
    block7 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs7_log, Ys7_log,ax=ax1)
    block8 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs8_log, Ys8_log,ax=ax1)
    block9 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs9_log, Ys9_log,ax=ax1)
    block10 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs10_log, Ys10_log,ax=ax1)
    block11 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs11_log, Ys11_log,ax=ax1)
    block12 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs12_log, Ys12_log,ax=ax1)
    block13 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs13_log, Ys13_log,ax=ax1)
    block14 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs14_log, Ys14_log,ax=ax1)
    block15 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs15_log, Ys15_log,ax=ax1)
    block16 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs16_log, Ys16_log,ax=ax1)
    block17 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs17_log, Ys17_log,ax=ax1)
    block18 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs18_log, Ys18_log,ax=ax1)
    block19 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs19_log, Ys19_log,ax=ax1)
    block20 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs20_log, Ys20_log,ax=ax1)
    block21 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs21_log, Ys21_log,ax=ax1)
    block22 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs22_log, Ys22_log,ax=ax1)
    block23 = amp.blocks.Scatter(Xs23_log, Ys23_log,ax=ax1)


    #ax1.legend()
    #ax2.legend()

    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4, hspace=0.6)
    plt.tick_params(labelbottom=False,
               labelleft=False)

    anim = amp.Animation([block,block2,block3,block4,block5,block6,block7,block8,block9,block10,block11,block12,block13,block14,block15,block16,block17,block18,block19,block20,block21,block22,block23])
    anim.controls()
    anim.save_gif("result")
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    csv_file_path = "test3.csv"

    
    ref_df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path, encoding= "utf-8-sig")    
    plot_animation(ref_df)

    print("finished!")
```

test3.csvの内容は以下のように座標データが入っているものになっております。

[image: test3.csv]

上記のコードを実行すると以下のようなものが出てきます。
便宜上画像を貼っておりますが実際はアニメーションのように動くようになっております。

[image: 出力]

これを以下のデータのように線で繋いだまま動くようにしたいと考えております。

[image: 理想]

具体的には以下の5本の線を引きたいと考えております。

```
block1-4,block5-8,block9-14,block15-20,block21,22,23,20
```

初心者のため、拙い質問で申し訳ありませんが、お力添えをいただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

現在の `ref_df` は縦軸に `t`, 横(カラム)に各座標の x,y が並んでいます
そこから `animatplot.blocks.Line` を使う場合, そのためのデータを用意しなければならない訳で, 加工が必要

例えば五角形と 2本の線を描画するとして
(ここでは, columnsを `x1` 〜 `xN`, `y1` 〜 `yN` に統一)

縦軸 `t`を無視して考えるなら …

- (x1,y1) 〜 (x6,y6) の 6点を縦軸に取り (6,2) の 2次元に変換し plot

縦軸 `t`を加味して plotするなら, 同様に 6点を縦軸に取る形に変換

```py
# 閉じた五角形のため 6 Point 使用
arr = np.array([(ref_df[f'x{n}'], ref_df[f'y{n}'])for n in range(1, 7)]).T
block = amp.blocks.Line(arr[:,0], arr[:,1], marker='o', ax=ax1)

# 3 Pointで 2本の線
arr = np.array([(ref_df[f'x{n}'], ref_df[f'y{n}'])for n in range(7, 10)]).T
block2 = amp.blocks.Line(arr[:,0], arr[:,1], ax=ax1)
```

[image: 描画の結果]

---

座標 21,22,23,20 … の場合は 順番が異なるので, ref_df 生成時あるいは読み取り後に入れ替えればよいかも

あるいは `x*_np`, `y*_np` (or `Xs*_log`, `Ys*_log`) のオブジェクトを直接使えば名前順関係なく利用可能。
例えば五角形で指定してる `range(1, 7)` の部分の場合, (6,2)==12 のオブジェクトのリストにして指定すると OK

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
気付くのに遅れてしまったため現在修正を試みております。
取り急ぎ感謝のご連絡をさせて頂きました。